# PHP script in FORM HTML <input>

Tags: php, html, forms, input

```
<form id="submit-form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>dateField1</label>
    <?php
    print "<b>calendar:</b><br/>";
    $dateField1 = new dateField($format,"date1",$img);
    $dateField1->setTitles($arr_daysOfTheWeek,$arr_months,$format_title);
    $dateField1->setCssClasses($arr_cssClasses);
    print "value:" . $dateField1->makeDateField();      
    ?>
    <input type="text" class="span3" name="dateField1" tabindex="2" value="php code" />
</form>
```

I want to make that **value** in php script ... be related to the **value** of the input form html
I tried so many ways ,but not implemented , please help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because "but not work" is **not** a problem description.

Comment: @PeeHaa just because something is not working doesn't mean the question is off topic, people ask questions about things not working all the time

Comment: Yeah that's the reason SO is becoming the next "debug meh codez for meeee" site instead of a decent resource.

Comment: PHP doesn't have a dateField object, for as far as I know. Show us that code too please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print "... value="'.$dateField1'" ... " />
```

Recheck this part, especially the quotes and the escaping

```
print "... ";
/* escaping a variable, this is actually not needed when using double quotes */
print "..." . $abc . "...";
print "... $abc ... ";
print '...' . $abc . '...';
/* escaping a var, but enclosing it in single quotes in the result code */
print "... abc='" . $def . "' ...";
```

For as far as I can see and derive from your comments below, you are using some kind of dateField object. This object contains some data and you're trying to use its value.
The data you enter in the value-tag of the input-field must be a `String`. But you are trying to put an `Object` in there. You must extract the value-data from the dateField-Object

---

This is a complete guess. But I have no info from you to work on...

I **assume** you *classes/dateField.class.php* looks something like this:

```
class dateField {
    function __contruct($format,$name,$img) {
        // ...
    }

    function setTitles($daysOfTheWeek,$months,$format_title) {
        // ...
    }

    function setCssClasses($cssClasses) {
        // ...
    }

    function makeDateField() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now you need to fill in these blanks:

- What does `makeDateField()` do?
  Does it return the HTML-code for a Date Field?
  Does it return a value (single value or array)?
- Is there some method that returns the value?
  E.g. `function getDate()` or something similar?

Comment: I write this code, and shows me this error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class dateField Could not be converted to string in 'This line' print '<input type =" text "class =" span3 "name =" dateField1 "value = '. $ dateField1.' /> '; "

Comment: <form id="submit-form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>dateField1</label>
 <?php
 include("config.php");
 include("classes/dateField.class.php");
 //datefield 1
 print "<b>Normal calendar:</b><br/>";
 $dateField1 = new dateField($format,"date1",$img);
 $dateField1->setTitles($arr_daysOfTheWeek,$arr_months,$format_title);
 $dateField1->setCssClasses($arr_cssClasses);
 print "valabil:" . $dateField1->makeDateField();
print '<input type="text" class="span3" name="dateField1"  value='.$dateField1.' />';
?>
</form>

Comment: @user3314763 Put that code in your question. That'll be much easier to read and debug. Also add the code of the dateField Object. I edited my answer, I hope it helps

Comment: and how to implement " input-field must be a String " in my script?
I do not know programming

Comment: i wrote this code
echo "<input type=text class=span3 name=dateField1  value='".htmlspecialchars($dateField1, ENT_QUOTES)."' >";
and says:Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in

Comment: @user3314763 Please edit your question above. It'll be much easier to read and others will be able to help you even better. I don't think htmlspecialchars is what you need, at least not to fix the issue. [PHP.net - HTML Special Chars](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: @user3314763 I need to know what this dateField object is. Show us the code that creates this object.

Comment: ok, I understand, I did edit my question above.

Comment: @user3314763 Please check the edit of my post. I (We) need more information. Otherwise your question will remain on *hold*

Comment: I assume that this information is enough, here only required to link the **value of the php script** and the **input value** (form thml) and ready